# How to import columns of worksheets to activate workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I would like to import specific columns to activate-workbook from user selected workbooks.

When I copy and paste the columns, it can not be pasted into the targeted sheet. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
Sub Import_sheet()

Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fDialog
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Select Files to prepare"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then

        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
            MsgBox varFile
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(varFile)
            'wb.Worksheets(1).Copy _
            After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)

            wb.Sheets(1).Columns("C").Select
            Selection.Copy

            activeWB.Sheets("template").Columns("B").Select
            Selection.Paste 

            wb.Close False

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Next

      Else
         MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
      End If
   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Activating the Workbook before Copy or Pasting so it's not out of range.

```
    wb.activate
    wb.Sheets(1).select
    wb.Sheets(1).Columns("C").Copy


    activeWB.activate
    activeWB.Sheets("template").select
    activeWB.Sheets("template").Cells("B1").Paste
```

Comment: No problem, could you please click the correct sign by the side of the answer :)

Comment: No Miguel, I activate the workbook as you mention and paste it under B column..
It is pretty ok... Thanks again

Comment: Just that you took down the correct answer symbol so I was wondering.